# Cannot run xmlhttprequest in Chrome App : provisional headers & No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am building a chrome app sending a Get HTTPRequest to an external API:
I get the answer:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key=FILDTEOIK2HBORODV&name=weezer.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://ihdfphmemcdeadpnjkhpihmcoeiklphe'
>   is   therefore not allowed access.

- I did allow the external domain in permissions in my manifest (to prevent blocking in cross domain requests)
- When I type the URL in the Address Bar it works perfectly

It seems **Chrome is blocking my request**, I even tried to load directly the script in an HTML page and it does not work (same message but with origin "null") (oh and it did not allow me to cheat by changing the Origin in the Header).
I also get the famous "Caution : Provisional Headers are shown" in the console, which makes me think Chrome is blocking my request, I looked up on other Stack Overflow Questions but apart running chrome://net-internals and looking for stuff I haven't the first clue about I cannot find any good answers (I did run chrome://net-internals but really can't make any sense out of it).

Here is the request :

```
function update_stations() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("Get","http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key=FILDTEOIK2HBORODV&name=weezer", true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("Essai");
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        console.log(xhr);
        document.getElementById("resp").innerText = xhr;
    }
    xhr.send()
}
```

Any thoughts (would be highly appreciated)?

Comment: Can you post your manifest permissions as well? There could easily be an error there that would prevent access.

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked as I repackaged the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr) chrome developer documentation explains that the host must be listed in the permissions of the manifest file.

I've taken the XHR code from above and included it in the hello world sample. It works after adding the following to the manifest.json.

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://*.echonest.com/"
  ]
```